# Is the %zu specifier required for printf?

Tags: c, printf, c89, size-t, c-libraries

We are using C89 on an embedded platform. I attempted to print out a `size_t`, but it did not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    size_t n = 123;
    printf("%zu\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of `123`, I got `zu`.
Other specifiers work correctly.

If `size_t` exists shouldn't  `zu` also be available in `printf`?
Is this something I should contact my library vendor about, or is a library implementation allowed to exclude it?

Comment: The `z` prefix was added in C99 I believe.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok.  It doesn't seem to be annotated.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: Why should a C++ reference say anything about a C standard?

Comment: [The Man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) has it...

Comment: [Here a some history](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/iz3hAqkS/)

Comment: Now marked on cppreference

Comment: @mch Right.  I meant to post the C reference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> If size_t exists shouldn't  zu also be available in printf?

`size_t` existed at least since C89 but the respective format specifier `%zu` (specifically the length modifier `z`) was added to the standard only since C99.

So, if you can't use C99 (or C11) and had to print `size_t` in C89, you just have to fallback to other existing types, such as:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)n);
```

Comment: Note that the above code would be sufficient, though not necessarily efficient, on any platform where `unsigned long` was large enough to accommodate the largest possible value of `n` (regardless of whether it was large enough to handle the full range of `size_t`).  There is no guarantee, however, that `size_t` won't be larger than `unsigned long`, and there might not be any guarantee that `n` would always fit in `unsigned long`.  I don't know how often that would be a problem [many programs could run into different trouble if they calculate the size of sprintf buffers...

Comment: ...based upon a presumption that the maximum length of a decimal-formatted unsigned long is 10 digits and the value to be output ends up being longer than that].

Comment: For better portability, use `printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)n);`, unless you know that the size is small, such as `sizeof(int)` in which case you can simply write `printf("%u\n", (unsigned)n);`

Comment: @chqrlie `unsigned long long` didn't exist in C89 - that's the reason I suggested `unsigned long`. If `unsigned long long` is available (C99), then `%zu` specifier for `size_t` would also be available. Thus there's no need to cast to `unsigned long long` here at all.

Answer (score -4):

size_t is returned by sizeof(). %zu specifier prints the length.So to return the size of n,the code should read: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { size_t n=123; printf("%zu\n",sizeof (n)); return 0;` }

Answer (score -9):

This is working fine. In my system, it's printing the expected value.
You may be getting the error due to the compiler. I am using the **GCC** compiler. If you have this only and trying to get the output the first update the GCC and then try. It will work.

[image: Your program input]

[image: The output of the program]

Comment: The problem is actually located in the C library. A common case where `%zu` is not supported is older versions of MinGW that use gcc in combination with the system's Microsoft C library, which until very recently did not support most C99 extensions.